# Commonjs - Moving data from one window to another using Titanium in Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, commonjs

I'm trying to pass data from a main window when a button is pressed on that page using `require()`, like so:

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor: '#333333',
            navTintColor: '#FFF',
            barColor: '#222222',
            itemID: evt.annotation.myid
        });
        Ti.API.info('detailWindow.itemID = ' + detailWindow.itemID); 
        // displays expected value from database eg 12345

        detailWindow = require('ui/iphone/detail');
        var detailWin = new myWindowHere(detailWindow.itemID);
}
```

In detail.js:

```
function myWindowHere(myItemID) {
    var myDetailsWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    //properties here
    });
    Ti.API.info('myItemID = ' + myItemID); // this log is never 
    var facilityID = myItemID;

    myWindowHere.open();

    return myDetailsWin;
};
module.exports = myWindowHere;
```

But, I've gone wrong somewhere as I'm getting error message: `Can't find variable: myItemID`

Please help! Many thanks

Comment: you create a window in `detailWindow` and override that variable with the `require` statement. Inside that you create a new window, why should `myItemID` be visible in there? Add methods to your module (e.g. `myDetailsWin.passParameter = function(){}` to pass in variables or add them to the require statement as a 2nd parameter

Comment: It looks like you need to learn a couple javascript basics. `new myWindowHere(detailWindow.itemID);` doesn't do anything, because the context doesn't know that object. `myWindowHere.open();` doesn't point to anything either. And as @miga said you're overriding an object and expect the original to still exist... that doesn't work like that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Any code examples on how to resolve this? I am indeed new to javascript, so finding this tricky. I need to populate detailWindow with data that is selected on main page, already pulled from database...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#333333',
        navTintColor: '#FFF',
        barColor: '#222222',
        itemID: evt.annotation.myid
    });
    Ti.API.info('detailWindow.itemID = ' + detailWindow.itemID); 
    // displays expected value from database eg 12345

    var detailWin = require('ui/iphone/detail').myWindowHere(detailWindow.itemID);
}
```